# Are there statements more easily shown to be provable than proved?

Tags: logic, formal-proofs

For specificity, fix ZFC as our axiom system, and assume it's consistent.

If we can prove some proposition $P$, then we can also prove $\square P$, "P is provable (in ZFC)", with some constant-factor additional work to turn each step of the proof into a demonstration that that step can be carried out in (some encoding of) the axioms.

However, this naive approach to conversion inevitably lengthens the proof in question. Are there easy-to-construct examples where the proof of $\square P$ is much shorter than the proof of $P$? Intuitively, this seems like it ought to be the case, as one frequently encounters situations where one can easily see that whatever the answer to a problem, it straightforwardly *exists* by computation, and this realization takes far less work than the computation itself.

If so, can the difference in length be made huge, in the sense that the shortest proof of $\square P$ is of length $n$, while the shortest proof of $P$ is on the order of $BB(n)$? (This is as good as could be hoped for, since a proof of $\square P$ must be at least as long as the length $k$ of the statement $P$, and we can make a Turing Machine of size $O(k)$ searching for proofs of $P$.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's write "$\Diamond_n P$" for "there is no proof of $\neg P$ of length $<n$." Just as $\Diamond\top$ is shorthand for "ZFC is consistent," the sentence $\Diamond_n\top$ is shorthand for "There is no contradiction in ZFC of length $<n$."

Each sentence of the form $\Box\Diamond_n\top$ is then almost trivially ZFC-provable. We argue (within ZFC) by cases:

- If $\Diamond_n\top$ is false, then ZFC proves everything (being inconsistent) and so in particular proves $\Diamond_n\top$.
- If $\Diamond_n\top$ is true, then ZFC can prove $\Diamond_n\top$ by simply checking all possible ZFC-proofs of length $<n$.

*(This second bulletpoint relies on the fact that ZFC proves its own $\Sigma^0_1$-completeness - see e.g. [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258431/who-first-proved-that-we-can-prove-that-we-prove-things-we-prove).)*

Now we go a bit further. For each $e$ which ZFC proves is an index for a total computable function, each appropriately-formulated sentence $$\theta^e_n\equiv\Diamond_{\varphi_e(n)}\top$$ have "provability proofs" not too dependent on $e$ (it only takes constant overhead to describe $\varphi_e$). Specifically:

> There is a (ZFC-provably-)total computable function $h$ such that for all $e$, if $e$ is an index for a ZFC-provably-total computable function then for all but finitely many $n$ there is a ZFC-proof of $\Box\theta^e_n$ of length $<h(n)$.

But we can now whip up an $e$ which is sufficiently fast-growing that for *no* $n$ is there a ZFC-proof of $\theta_n^e$ of length $<h(n)$.

- *(HINT: $\varphi_e(x)$ should be the least $k$ such that there is no proof of ...)*.

If you want a bigger gulf, just replace the $h$ above with a needlessly-bigger function $\hat{h}$; the corresponding $\hat{e}$ for $\hat{h}$ will then have the property that no $\theta^\hat{e}_n$ has a ZFC-proof of length $<\hat{h}(n)$, but still for all but finitely many $n$ the sentence $$\Box\theta^\hat{e}_n$$ has a ZFC-proof of length $<h(n)$. The bigger the gulf between $h$ and $\hat{h}$, the bigger the "eventual slowdown" we see.

---

Meanwhile, there is a sort of computable bound on the slowdown we can see here. Assuming ZFC is $\Sigma_1$-sound, there is a total computable $j$ such that for every sentence $\varphi$, if $\Box\varphi$ has a proof of length $<n$ then $\varphi$ has a proof of length $<j(n)$. This $j$ is simple to describe: first enumerate each of the finitely many sentences with provability proofs of length $<n$, and now search for actual proofs of each such sentence and record the longest such. The second half of this algorithm works if ZFC is $\Sigma_1$-sound.

So there is in fact a computable bound to the slowdown we can have, as long as ZFC is $\Sigma_1$-sound. Meanwhile, if ZFC is *not* $\Sigma_1$-sound then there is a sentence $\psi$ such that ZFC proves $\Box \psi$ but ZFC does not prove $\psi$, so the question doesn't even make sense without that hypothesis.

Comment: This means that $j(n)$, while totally computable, grows faster than every ZFC-provably-total function (as we could choose any such function to be our $\hat{h}$), right?

Comment: @RavenclawPrefect Yup - since the totality of $j$ is in fact equivalent to the $\Sigma_1$-soundness of the theory in question (here, ZFC).